# Use algebra of Big-O notation to express tan($z$)

Tags: complex-numbers, asymptotics

We can use the definition of Big-O notation to simply prove that

$\sin(z)=z-\frac{z^3}{6}+O(z^5)$ as $z\rightarrow 0$,

$\cos(z)=1-\frac{z^2}{2}+O(z^4)$ as $z\rightarrow 0$
and

$\tan(z)=z+\frac{z^3}{3}+O(z^5)$ as $z\rightarrow 0$.

by using the power series of sin, cos and tan.

But my question is we know that $\tan(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{\cos(z)}$, so we can write

$\tan(z)=\frac{z-\frac{z^3}{6}+O(z^5)}{1-\frac{z^2}{2}+O(z^4)}$ by the previous results.

However, how to use the algebra of Big-O to show that

$z+\frac{z^3}{3}+O(z^5)=\frac{z-\frac{z^3}{6}+O(z^5)}{1-\frac{z^2}{2}+O(z^4)}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Starting at "so we can write", the question becomes bizarre, forgetting initial terms in expansions.

Comment: I corrected that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You mistyped your $\cos$, that should be $\cos z = 1 - \frac{z^2}{2} + O(z^4)$, and in your fraction for $\tan$, you forgot the leading terms of numerator and denominator (and have the wrong signs for the next term in each). Correcting that, expanding the denominator into (the beginning of) a geometric series yields

$$\begin{align}
\tan z &= \frac{z - \frac{z^3}{6} + O(z^5)}{1-\frac{z^2}{2} + O(z^4)}\\
&= \left(z - \frac{z^3}{6} + O(z^5)\right)\cdot \left(1 + \left(\frac{z^2}{2} + O(z^4)\right) + O\left(\left(\frac{z^2}{2} + O(z^4)\right)^2\right)\right)\\
&= \left(z - \frac{z^3}{6} + O(z^5)\right)\cdot \left(1 + \frac{z^2}{2} + O(z^4)\right)\\
&= z - \frac{z^3}{6} + O(z^5) + \frac{z^3}{2} - \frac{z^5}{12} + O(z^7) + z\cdot O(z^4)\\
&= z + \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{6}\right)z^3 + O(z^5)\\
&= z + \frac{z^3}{3} + O(z^5).
\end{align}$$

Comment: In the fourth row, why there is a $O(z^7)$ and where is $z\cdot O(z^4)$ in the following row?

Comment: The $O(z^7)$ comes from $\frac{z^3}{6}\cdot O(z^4)$, and $z\cdot O(z^4)$ is $O(z^5)$, so that is absorbed.

Comment: I am sorry I am confused, like, for example, what is $O(z^4)\cdot O(z^5)$ and what is $O(z^4)+O(z^5)$? And why $z \cdot O(z^4)=O(z^5)$ and $z^3/6 \cdot O(z^4)=O(z^7)$? Are these from the definitions of Big-O notation?

Comment: $f(z) \in O(z^k)$ means there is a constant $C$ with $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant C\cdot \lvert z^k\rvert$. So if $f \in O(z^k)$ and $g \in O(z^m)$, then $(f\cdot g) \in O(z^{k+m})$, and $(f+g) \in O(z^{\min \{k,m\}})$ as $z\to 0$, and $(f+g) \in O(z^{\max \{k,m\}})$ as $z\to\infty$.

Comment: Is $-O(z)$ the same as $O(z)$?

Comment: Constant factors ($\neq 0$) are irrelevant for $O$, so yes, $-O(z) = O(z) = 10^{257}O(z)$.